# Changing chart from 2d to 3d caused one series to hide behind the other

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have a chart that displays as expected side by side when 
`Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False`
but when I set it to true one of the series disappears behind the other rather than side by side.
I cannot find anything in the charts properties in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.  Set isCluster to True 
`Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.IsClustered = True`